# Simple problem with TwistStamped msg

Tags: ros, gazebo, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi Ros users:

I am trying to do an array of velocities. This is my code:

```
  geometry_msgs::Twist cmd;
  geometry_msgs::TwistStamped tiempo;
  cmd.linear.x = 1; 
  cmd.linear.y = 0;
  cmd.linear.z = 0;
  
  tiempo.header.stamp=5;
  cmd.angular.x = 0;
  cmd.angular.y = 0;
  cmd.angular.z = 4;
  vel_pub_.publish(cmd);
```

But when it is compiled i can see these errors on terminal

> /home/alcor/catkin_ws/src/lanzar_velocidades/src/arrayvel.cpp:52:3:
> error: ‘geometry’ has not been
> declared    geometry::TwistStamped
> tiempo;    ^
> /home/alcor/catkin_ws/src/lanzar_velocidades/src/arrayvel.cpp:52:26:
> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘tiempo’
> geometry::TwistStamped tiempo;
> ^ /home/alcor/catkin_ws/src/lanzar_velocidades/src/arrayvel.cpp:57:3:
> error: ‘tiempo’ was not declared in
> this scope    tiempo.header.stamp=5;
> ^ make[2]: ***
> [lanzar_velocidades/CMakeFiles/arrayvel_node.dir/src/arrayvel.cpp.o]
> Error 1 make[1]: ***
> [lanzar_velocidades/CMakeFiles/arrayvel_node.dir/all]
> Error 2

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213583/simple-problem-with-twiststamped-msg/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

stamp must be a ros::Time object. Also 5 seems quite arbitrary and is probably not gonna do what you want it to do.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0